# Is there an alternative to JObject.TryGetValue(string role, value:out var output) in .NET Core 3.X version?

Tags: .net-core-3.1

I am migrating to .NET Core 3.X from .NETCore 2.2 and am trying to get following code to work

```
private static Task SetUserInformationReceived(UserInformationReceivedContext context)
{
   if (context.User.TryGetValue(JwtClaimTypes.Role, value: out var roles)){ 
      //Code comes here
   }
}
```

But in .NET Core 3.X UserInformationReceivedContext.User is now a JsonDocument instead of JObject, rendering above code not usable. Is there any other way to get the JToken here with the specified property name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found a solution for this question, and seeing there was no online solution, I'll be posting it here.

```
    private static Task SetUserInformationReceived(UserInformationReceivedContext context){
        if (context.User.RootElement.TryGetProperty(JwtClaimTypes.Role, value : out var roles)){ 
            //Code comes here
        }
    }
```